# directory resetting to C:\Users\Name

Tags: python, python-2.7

Today I began having problems with changing the directory. os.chdir() and cd do not work: the directory resets to C:\Users\Name every time in python and qt console.

This has never happened before.

Comment: You're very unclear: what commands are you *exactly* executing, and how do you determine the directory you're in? Keep in mind that generally, the `chdir()` function works only for that specific session.

Comment: If you have done *exactly* the same thing previously, and then results were different, I'd think very hard what I've changed in my setup (environment variables, updates, etc).

Comment: @Evert : I have done exactly the same thing previously, using cd <dir> and os.chdir(<dir>). The strange thing is that on both of my computers this is happening all of a sudden. I really don't know what could have changed.

Comment: Update your question with the *exact* command you execute, and then show how you determine that the directory resets. Your current question and comment are too general to know what may be wrong.